# Drupal theming using tpl file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How to present the fields of my form in a way that every row has 2 fields in Drupal 7? I want to do it using `tpl.php` files instead of directly through CSS. Could anyone please help?

Below I have provided the basic code of my form. Please check it out and tell if anything else is required.

```
  $items['example/mfrp']=array(
        'title'=>'Example Form',
        'dsecription'=>'My first Real Time Project',
        'page callback'=>'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'=>array('mfrp_form'),
        'access callback'=>TRUE,
    );



 function mfrp_form($form,&$form_state){
    $form['name']=array(
        '#title'=>t("University Name"),
        '#type'=>'textfield',
        //'#value'=> t("Enter University name"),
        '#placeholder' => t('Enter your name here'),
        '#required'=> TRUE,


    );
    $form['address']=array(
        '#title'=>t("Unversity Address"),
        '#type'=> 'textfield',
        //'#value'=> t("Enter University address"),
        '#placeholder' => t('Enter your address here'),
        '#required'=> TRUE,


    );
     $form['#attributes']['enctype'] = 'multipart/form-data'; // If this is not
    // Here, upload will fail on submit
    // $form['#attributes']['placeholder'] = "Enter your input here";
   $form['logo'] = array(
        '#title'=> t('University Logo'),
        '#type'         => 'file',
        '#value'=>t("Enter University logo"),
        //'#required'=> TRUE,
        '#description'  => t('Images must be one of jpg, gif or png formats.'),

    );


$form['specialisation'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Choose your specialisation'),
    '#description' => t('Select a University Specialisation'),
    '#options' => array(
    t('Arts'),
    t('Commerce'),
    t('Science')),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['specialisation']) ? $form_state['values']['specialisation'] : '',
    '#required'=> TRUE,
    );

    $form['website']=array(
        '#title'=>t("Univerity Website"),
        '#type'=>'textfield',
        //'#value'=>t("Enter University website"),
        '#placeholder' => t('Enter your website here'),
        '#required'=>TRUE,
    );

    $form['newsletter']=array(
        '#type'=>'checkbox',
        '#title'=>t("Do you want to receive newsletters in your email"),
        '#required'=>TRUE,
    );

    $form['submit']=array(
        '#type'=>'submit',
        '#value'=>'Submit',
        '#required'=>TRUE,
        '#submit' => array('mfrp_form_submit'),
        );

    return $form;    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose you need something [like that](https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122). You may trace content of $form variable to see structure of it (via [dpm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7.x-1.x) for example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.how does dpm help in changing the formatting of form fields? Actually I am just a couple of weeks old in Drupal 7.

Comment: You may output(via dpm) $form variable in corresponding template (see article) and observe the structure (this variable consists all information about form that is needed to render). Then you may render it according this structure as you wish.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same using #theme?

Comment: Could you not repeat the same $form[name] array with a different [name] ?? for eg 
`$form['website_']=array(
        '#type'=>'textfield',
        //'#value'=>t("Enter University website"),
        '#placeholder' => t('Enter your website here'),
        '#required'=>TRUE,
    );`
adding a `_` would also be useful during validation.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Sanjok.